# How to refresh a plotly figure after dataframe update?

Tags: python, plotly

Let's say that you've built a figure using `px.line()` using a dataframe, and the dataframe later has new data added to it. What's a good approach to refresh your figure with new data? An example could be `px.data.stocks`, where you start out with a subset of the columns `['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'AMZN', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'MSFT']`, for example `['GOOG', 'AAPL']`, and that after building the figure, `['AMZN', 'FB', 'NFLX', 'MSFT']` is added to the dataframe.

#### Example plot

[image]

#### Example code

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# figure
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns[:2])
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short answer:

```
exist = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: exist.append(t.name))
[fig.add_scatter(x=df.index, y = df[col], mode = 'lines', name = col) for col in df.columns if col not in exist]
```

#### The details:

Often, just rebuilding the figure with a new call to `px.line()` with the new dataset will do just fine. But you can also retrieve the names of the traces in your `fig` using:

```
exist = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: exist.append(t.name))
```

And then check which of the trace names in your updated dataset are not already in the figure and include those as well with `fig.add_scatter()` like this:

```
[fig.add_scatter(x=df.index, y = df[col], mode = 'lines', name = col) for col in df.columns if col not in exist]
```

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# data
df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

# figure
fig = px.line(df, x = df.index, y = df.columns[:2])

# refresh figure with updated dataset
exist = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: exist.append(t.name))
[fig.add_scatter(x=df.index, y = df[col], mode = 'lines', name = col) for col in df.columns if col not in exist]
fig.show()
```