# How to refresh the Plotly chart in same instance

Tags: python, charts, plotly, refresh, python-datetime

I am extracting intraday stock prices in 1m interval and displaying the results in Plotly candlestick chart.
Issue is my code creates a new chart every minute data is extracted which will kill the memory.

1. I want guidance to refresh the same instance of plotly chart every time data is refreshed
2. Even after provide datetime to xaxis, xaxis is not displaying any info/data

I want guidance to refresh the same instance of plotly chart every time data is refreshed & understand why xaxis is not showcasing the time data.

How to go about doing the same.

Below is my code:

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
from time import time, sleep
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pytz 
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd

# Below package is being used to get the sample data only
import plotly.express as px

###

dataavl = 0
def GetData():
    
    if dataavl == 0:
        Data = px.data.stocks()
        Data['date']= pd.to_datetime(Data['date'])
        # Only taking first 100 rows to create the initial chart out of 105rows
        Data =  Data.head(100)
    else:
        # using the complete data to refersh the graph. This includes the last 105rows.
        # Now I want to refersh to chart to showcase the complete 105rows
        Data = px.data.stocks()
        Data['date']= pd.to_datetime(Data['date'])
    return Data


def Create_Chart(df):
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=1,shared_xaxes=True,vertical_spacing=0.080)
    
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=df['date'],y=df['GOOG'], name = 'Live Volume'),row=1, col=1)
   
    # Add titles
    fig.update_layout(
            title={
            'text': "TESLA Live Share Price",
            #'y':0.9,
            'x':0.50,
            'xanchor': 'center',
            'yanchor': 'top'},
            yaxis_title='Stock Price ($ per Shares)',margin=dict(b=1),
            yaxis2_title = 'Volume' )

    
    fig.update_xaxes(
          rangeslider_visible=False,
          rangeselector=dict(
          buttons=list([
                  dict(count=1, label="1m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                  dict(count=15, label="15m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                  dict(count=45, label="45m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                  dict(count=1, label="HTD", step="hour", stepmode="todate"),
                  dict(count=3, label="3h", step="hour", stepmode="backward"),
                  dict(step="all")
                ])
            ))
    
    fig.update_layout(xaxis2_rangeslider_visible=True, xaxis3_rangeslider_thickness=0.00,autosize=False,
    width=1250,
    height=900,
    legend=dict(
        x=0,
        y=.5,
        traceorder="normal",
        font=dict(
            family="sans-serif",
            size=12,
            color="black",
            
        )),            
    margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=10,
        t=10,
        pad=4
    ))

    
    fig.show()


# Testing the while loop
while True:
    
    Data = GetData() 
    nyc_time = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('US/Eastern'))
    print(f'Data Extracted at : {nyc_time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]}')
    
    Create_Chart(Data)
    print(f'Chart Created at : {nyc_time.strftime("%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]}')
    dataavl = 1
    
    sleep(60 - time() % 60)
```

Requesting guidance

Regards
Sudhir

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refresh a plotly figure after dataframe update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69390460/how-to-refresh-a-plotly-figure-after-dataframe-update)

Comment: @rpanai thanks for your guidance, to test the solution provided in link suggested by you, I have loaded two datasets, Data have 100 rows and Data2 have 110 rows. Since I do not want to add more traces hence I am only using the codes "exist = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: exist.append(t.name))". Below is the code modified by me for my context - "exist = []
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: exist.append(Data2.tail(29)))" but still its creating a new instance of the chart and also not updating the new data to the chart. i.e. 20 new rows. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: @kbsudhir As your question now stands, it's not reproducible and not very focused. If I understand correctly, your goal here is not to extend the number of traces in your figure, but rather to extend the length of the traces that already exist. If that is in fact the case, please consider making your question reproducible by using the dataset `px.data.stocks()`

Comment: thanks @vestland . Was under the weather one week hence was not able to check. Yes you are right I want to extend the length of the existing traces (Candlestick trace) with added timestamps. Will make the changes to the code as suggested by you.

Comment: @vestland I have updated the code as suggested to get the sample data. The code creates a new chart for each update rather than refreshing the existing chart by increasing the length of the existing trace. I am using two subplots with candlestick and bar traces. But in sample code I am just using one plot with line trace for ease of readability and  reproducibility of using sample data set.

Comment: Any help is appreciated